# Displaying WooCommerce get_date_created() as ddmmyyyy, not yyyy-mm-dd+time

Tags: php, date, woocommerce, reference, numbers

I'm trying to display a reference number with order on hold for Direct Bank Transactions with WooCommerce. I added

```
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'Za referenco (sklic) uporabite "SI 00 ' . $order->get_order_number() . $order->get_date_created() . ' ". ', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```

to customer-on-hold-order.php (which I copied to my child theme. It works, but the result is shown as

```
Za referenco (sklic) uporabite "SI 00 48522021-12-27T09:10:49+01:00 ".,
```

and in this case I would need it shown as

```
Za referenco (sklic) uporabite "SI 00 485227122021 ".
```

How can I modify the displayed date?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date()` to convert the date to what you want

```
<p>
    <?php esc_html_e( 'Za referenco (sklic) uporabite "SI 00 ' .
        $order->get_order_number() . 
        date('dmY',strtotime($order->get_date_created())) . 
        ' ". ', 'woocommerce' ); 
    ?>
</p>
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much!